# Matlab: Permute only columns of a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, permutation, sparse-matrix

I want to permute only columns of a sparse matrix in Matlab.

I can perform both row and column permutation via following command:

```
permutedSparseMatrix=sparseMatrix(rowPermutation, columnPermutation);
```

Comment: could you not just replace `rowPermutation` with the original indices `[1,2,...` (or more generically `1:size(sparseMatrix,1)`) so the rows order is unchanged?

Comment: or more simpily replace rowPermutation with a colon `:`

Answer (score 1):

`permutedSparseMatrix = sparseMatrix(:,columnPremutation)`